# Firestore: Something reseted shard value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm trying to implement [shards counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) to my app. I have the next firestore collection structure:
[image]

When I want to update counter, I call this method:

```js
  public updateCounter(ref: DocumentReference, num_shards: number, type: 'inc' | 'dec'): Promise<void> {
    const shard_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * num_shards).toString();
    const shard_ref = ref.collection('shards').doc(shard_id);

    return shard_ref.set({
      'count': firestore.FieldValue.increment(type === 'dec' ? -1 : 1)
    }, { merge: true });
  }
```

This is the place where I call it:

```js
const starsRef = this.fireStore.collection('counters')
                               .doc('stars')
                               .collection('companies')
                               .doc(this.cid).ref

this.countersService.updateCounter(starsRef, 5, 'inc')
```

But the problem, every time I make a call, it's increment `count` value of random shard, but also, it reset count to 0 for all other shards. I can't understand, why it works like this and what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you shared that would explain all shards being overwritten. Your `updateCounter` as far as I can see only writes a single document. So if you see all documents being updated, I'd set a breakpoint in `updateCounter` and see if you're maybe calling it multiple times.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like the behavior you describe can be due to the provided code as there are no decrements (where you call it from). You should check whether there's somewhere else you are calling `updateCounter` from, or setting the counters to 0.